# ¿Cómo crear una búsqueda en lista a partir de un rango? Python

Tags: python, lista

Suponer que tenemos una lista con 10 elementos. Deseo iniciar la búsqueda a partir de la posición numero 5 de la lista y recorrer la lista hasta el final para encontrar un elemento **"x"** que yo sé que se encuentra en ese rango.

Ejemplo: **No es relevante que la lista esté ordenada, sólo es para ejemplificar***

```
 miLista = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Quiero encontrar el número 7 iniciando la búsqueda a partir del la posición 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te presento la función `index` de Python. Se usa para buscar dentro de listas:

**list.index(x[, start[, end]])**

Retorna el índice basado en cero del primer elemento cuyo valor sea igual a `x`. Lanza una excepción `ValueError` si no existe tal elemento.

Los argumentos opcionales `start` y `end` son interpretados como la notación de rebanadas y se usan para limitar la búsqueda a un segmento particular de la lista. El índice retornado se calcula de manera relativa al inicio de la secuencia completa en lugar de con respecto al argumento `start`.

**Ejemplo**

Encontrar el primer valor "5" a partir de la cuarta posición de la lista:

```
miLista = ["5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
print(miLista.index("5", 3))
```

Retorna 5.